# How to pull defect/test execution report from Rally using its REST API thru SoapUI?

Tags: rest, excel, soapui, rally, vba

I am trying to get defect report/test execution report from Rally. Came to know that it can be done thru using its webservices/REST API. When tried to search how it can be done thru SoapUI (as it can also be used for REST Service) - got no info.

So can anyone please guide how it can be done??

if it cannot be done thru SoapUI - does anyone have any info on using VBA for getting similar report from Rally?

Comment: What have you got so far? If you have the REST API, then just plug into SoapUI: http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Rally stopped supporting SOAP and XML since the release of the current v2.0 of WS API.
The 2.0 version of the Rally API is REST based and uses JSON format.
You will have to make REST requests in SoapUI as user4211235 and SiKing suggested.

If you choose to use SOAP(which is not supported), there is a KnowledgeBase article [here](https://rallydev.force.com/answers?id=kA0a0000000YeAN). WSDL URLs for your workspaces can be found if you switch to older version of WS API, e.g.

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/?version=1.43

Rally makes WSDL URLs available for older version of WS API but there are no guarantees that all changes made in later version of API are backwards compatible as far as WSDL is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP UI does offer a RESTful interface. You should be able to point it to the REST endpoint that you are interested in as identified by Rally Webservices API docs:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

And issue the requests you're interested in. Check the SOAP UI docs for how to make REST requests -  SiKing's comment above on your question has the link.

If you need to pull data from Rally into Excel, your best bet is the Rally Add-in for Excel:

https://help.rallydev.com/rally-add-excel

Since you mentioned VBA, there is an alpha-level Rally Rest Toolkit for VBA. It is unofficial and not supported by Rally, but could be worth trying. Since it is unsupported though, Rally can't help you out if you run into issues. You'd have to write your own code against the VBA toolkit to pull the data you want:

https://github.com/markwilliams970/RallyRestToolkitForVBA